# VPS Admin Panel

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lamp, webmin

I got a simple question. I have this VPS hosted on Linode.com and I am currently using webmin and virtualmin. I have one domain, do not plan to have to multiple domains, I want subdomain and my dns will be be managed by my provider dns tool.

I will be using php7, redmine, and install a nominatim instance meaning I will have mysql, php7, ruby, postgresql, passenger and will mainly use php7 with probably php7-fpm and also use smtp on ubuntu 14.04.

Now, using webmin and virtualmin has been overly complicated to do anything. In fact, I spent most of time on the terminal than trying to set up the server through webmin/virtualmin.

Now that you know my needs. Do you think that an admin panel + webhosting panel is useful for my specific case or could I simply use a basic lamp stack without all the cumbersomeness of admin panels.

Everything got so messed up because of virtualmin that uses some sort of unique cgi/fcgi bin to transfer data and because its not compatible php7, I had to manually edit those files but they were protected with something that makes sudo not work (special type of file, do not remember the name). Anyhow, I'm just tired of using virtualmin and I will reset my whole installation.

Should I stick with webmin/virtualmin or perhaps only webmin or maybe ispconfig or simply install a lamp stack manually and forget about virtualmin.

Sorry for the long wall of text.

Comment: When in doubt, [dike](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dike.html) it out.

Comment: Worth reading: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels

Comment: Virtualmin does support PHP7 (https://www.virtualmin.com/virtualmin/whats-new-in-5.0). Virtualmin sets up fcgid and suexec in a way that allows each domain to have its own configuration; it's not particularly weird, and is mostly done the way most people document setting up fcgid and suexec, though we do a couple things differently with groups so that permissions can be a bit tighter on the website content directory. Virtualmin does not prevent sudo from working, and it is usually safe to modify configuration on the command line (unlike most control panels). (Disclaimer: I work on Virtuamin.)

Comment: no even though the doc says you support php7, your fcgi must be edited `Error writing php5.fcgi: Permission denied` in order and for that you gotta remove the `immutable attribute` (sudo doesn't work with `immutable attribute` files). I didn't invent things https://www.virtualmin.com/node/16992 However, I think it comes down to personal preference and virtualmin gives too much problems personally. I would rather start with nothing and if I ever get pissed of doing things manually, I would then switch to an admin panel. Otherwise, the benefits are not worth the cost.

Comment: I'm sorry you found Virtualmin frustrating. fcgi should not need to be edited manually to use PHP7; there are likely some types of installation of PHP7 (or other versions) that Virtualmin doesn't recognize (like those installed from source instead of from a package, probably, since a source install can end up *anywhere*). But the UI has support for altering that without changing the fcgi files. The immutable bit is to prevent non-privileged users from removing files that could cause Apache to not start. If you have root, you can unset immutable and make changes..but, again, not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do. Not. Use. An. Admin. Panel. Ok?

:)

Seriously, though. They're universally clumsy, they do odd things to your servers that make them impossible or difficult to troubleshoot via standard means, and perhaps worst of all, they actively prevent you from learning proper systems administration, and from acquiring the knowledge and skills necessary to do your job and to troubleshoot things.

Truth be told, Webmin is the least bad of the bunch. The rest? They're not worth the bits they're made of.

If you need to automate repetitive tasks on your server (a frequent feature that draws people to admin panels), then do so using a proper configuration management system.

Comment: Webmin can actually be beneficial to have... but only as a system administrator who already knows their stuff. Just keep a healthy idea of what Webmin is good for and what should be done in the terminal. Usermin is also very good webmail, by the way.